# Searching Python dictionary keys

Tags: python, mysql

I started coding for "real" in Matlab back in 2000. When you created an array you could search the keys of that array simply and quickly. It was like this:

```
found_keys = find(my_array(:, 1) > start_time & my_array(:, 1) < end_time)
```

Where my_array was an array (matrix really) with the first column being a timestamp in this example. The return would a list of those timestamps that were greater than start_time and less than end_time. I could then loop through found_keys to process only the data in my_array that was relevant.

I'm now working in Python with data that has a timestamp and I'm trying to match data from 2 different sources which report their time in different timezones but don't tell what those timezones are. The data from both sources is made up of lots (40k and 10K) individual events. The 10K represent individual events reported by both sources. The 2 sources share 3 fields with identical values.

So ideally I would determine the timestamp of an individual event from the 10k source. I would then create a time window - +/- 12 hours that would define the start_time and end_time for my searching. Then I'd search only the individual events from the 40k source that have timestamps between start_time and end_time.

In Matlab that would be extremely easy but in Python I have to use OrderedDict to get the timestamp keys sorted from low to high. I still don't know of any equivalent to the find function Matlab had. So instead I'm stuck looping through the 40k source for each of the 10k events. Obviously, once I find a match I can kick out of the loop and even pop the value off the dict but that will only speed up the search so much. Being ordered I can kick out of the loop after the timestamp is greater than end_time as well. But again these simple optimizations leave a lot to be desired.

While my current dataset of 40k and 10k isn't so huge I can't just do the big search and wait a while for the result I'd prefer a much faster method.

Any ideas?

--- Edit to show results: 02/25/2015 ---

I was partial to the dictionary comprehension since the end result was a dictionary of the values I need for downstream code. And the time was fast enough that it didn't matter much. However, the numpy solution was, by far, the fastest. Here are the numbers:

1. Numpy: 0.47 ms
2. List with Chained Comparisons: 11.30 ms
3. Dictionary Comprehension: 11.82 ms

All 3 solution provided identical answers. For my test it reduced 43,977 individual events to 49. If I were only running this a few times any and all of the solution would be perfectly adequate but I could be running this code thousands of times and so the difference between numpy and everything else becomes important.

Comment: Is your data a dict where the keys are timestamp strings?  Or is it something less structured than that?

Comment: For both sources, I've reformatted the data such that the event ID is the dict key. And in most of the cases this key matches for both sources and linking the 2 is simple. Occasionally it doesn't. So I created an index where the timestamps (floats) are the keys and the event ID of the 40k source is value. Specifically for the purposes of doing this search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use numpy arrays instead of OrderedDict, the syntax is really close to that of Matlab.

For instance, your example line becomes:

```
found_keys = numpy.where((my_array[:, 0] > start_time)*(my_array[:, 0] < end_time))[0]
```

Note that Matlab's `&` is changed to `*` in Python, but numpy also includes [logical_and](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) that would do the same.

Comment: The thought occurred to me as I finished writing this question but I haven't used numpy much - yet. So while I figured there was a way I wasn't sure what it would be.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `list` (An array that can handle multiple types) you can use list comprehension to get them! You can do the following:

```
new_list = [something(i) for i in list if condition]
```

This is the basic syntax. Combined with comparison chaining (`x > y >= z` etc.)

```
found_keys = [i for i in my_array if end_time > i > start_time]
```

would be your list, where `my_array` is the list of timestamps.

Comment: I have a dict so I'm assuming you would suggest converting the dict keys (the timestamps) into a list and then running your second line with the chained comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Dict Comprehension, which is like a list comprehension, but for dicts.

```
data = {0: 'w', 1: 's', 2: 'e', 3: 'r', 4: 'v', 5: 'a', 6: 's', 7: 'r', 8: 'e', 9: 'w', 10: 'v', 11: 'a', 12: 's'}
start_timestamp = 3
end_timestamp = 6
filtered_data = {k:v for k, v in data.iteritems() if k > start_timestamp and k < end_timestamp}
```

result:
`{4: 'v', 5: 'a'}`

Comment: This would be ideal since it returns both the key and the value into a new dict. I'm loading in all the data right now - takes several minutes. Once done I'll try all 3 solutions. Let you know which is fastest.